# Is it acceptable to ask a user a question by editing one of their posts?

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits, faq-proposed

I recently noticed the note,

> what is DOMdocument control?

was added to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122607/what-is-the-best-way-to-consume-a-web-service-from-vb6/123285#123285) by an anonymous user. The edit comment was, "please expalain in full."

I was surprised that this edit was approved and my question is:

**Was the approval a mistake, or is adding little editorial notes making suggestions for improvements indeed accepted practice?**

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Notes like that should be comments not edits. The approval was a mistake - definitely not accepted practice.

Answer (score 7):

It was 100% someone's mistake.

My guess is that someone probably misclicked "accept". Second accept was from someone not reviewing, just flying around suggested edits.

I have already rollbacked to the first revision

Answer (score 5):

It was clearly a mistake. If somebody doesn't understand what reported in an answer, he asks in a comment what the OP meant; it doesn't change the answer to add a question about the answer itself.

In this case, who proposed the edit is probably a user who doesn't have the reputation to write a comment to questions asked by somebody else, or somebody that doesn't have an account at all, and thought to use the proposed edit to ask what should have been asked in a comment.